# Convirtiendo oraciones afirmativas en preguntas

Tags: preguntas

¿Es gramaticalmente correcto formar una pregunta en español con tan sólo cambiar la entonación y agregar signos de interrogación?

Por ejemplo: "La mujer alta es de un pueblo del norte." ¿La mujer alta es de un pueblo del norte?

Comment: Por ejemplo: "La mujer alta es de un pueblo del norte." 
¿La mujer alta es de un pueblo del norte?

Answer (score 6):

Sí, en español las preguntas se forman más que nada con la entonación tanto de la frase completa como de las palabras. Por ejemplo, las palabras "como" y "cómo" solo varían por la forma en que las pronunciamos y la tilde sirve aquí para diferenciar esa entonación.

Ahora, podemos distinguir dos tipos de pregunta: las preguntas de sí o no y las preguntas de información. En las primeras solo varía la entonación de la frase; usualmente es una inflección hacia arriba, por ejemplo:

> ¿La mujer alta es de un pueblo del norte?

Aquí la respuesta que esperas es un sí o un no, y la única diferencia con "La mujer alta es de un pueblo del norte" (que es una afirmación) es la entonación.

En las preguntas de información no hay inflección hacia arriba, y lo que determina que sea una pregunta es el uso de algún pronombre o adverbio interrogativo (y estos son los que llevan una entonación diferente). Por ejemplo,
"¿De dónde era la mujer alta?" difiere de "de donde era la mujer alta" solo en la entonación de la palabra "donde".

Answer (score 3):

Cuando el sujeto se encuentra al inicio de la oración y es relativamente largo (en general mayor a una o dos palabras), en general queda fuera de la pregunta:

- La mujer alta, ¿es de un pueblo del norte?

En cambio, cuando el sujeto está pospuesto, la pregunta abarca la totalidad de la oración:

- ¿Es de un pueblo del norte la mujer alta?

Answer (score 2):

No, no lo es.

Te doy unos ejemplos:

`Porque lo digo yo`.
lo correcto sería `¿por qué lo digo yo?` Si te fijas, `Porque` cambia por `por qué`.

Con lo que podemos decir que en muchos casos sí pero no en todos, preguntate qué tipo de palabra es `porque` y qué es `por qué`. Pero ahí te va un ejemplo que no cumple tu regla.

Además en español nos basamos mucho en el contexto de la oración, con lo que hacer una frase interrogativa no es tan sencillo, depende de lo que quieras preguntar. Por lo que tu afirmación es ambigua.

Comment: "-Vamos a cenar sushi. -¿Porque lo dices tú? -Sí, porque lo digo yo.". Poner signos de interrogación a una frase afirmativa sirve para hacer una pregunta de tipo sí/no. Preguntar "por qué?" es otra cosa.

Comment: cierto, pero imagínate este otro contexto: vamos a cenar sushi. Por qué? porque lo digo yo. Y te puedes meter en las preguntas retóricas, cambios de persona, como tú ya has indicado, etc...